# grep */* - Invalid argument when Cygwin used in Windows cmd emulators

Tags: grep, cygwin

I use the following to grep in the current directory and all subdirectories:

```
grep -r 'some text' */*
```

This works fine in Cygwin, but when I configure Windows cmd emulators like Console2 or ConEmu to use Cygwin, the command does not work:

```
grep: */*: Invalid argument
```

1. Is there some technical reason why ***/*** does not port to these applications?
2. Is there another way of grepping across the current directory and subdirectories?

Many thanks

Comment: I see the same thing. I know that the Windows `cmd` shell handles wildcards differently than Unix-like shells so,  and in particular `*/*` doesn't seem to work. I don't know the details of why it's getting an `Invalid argument` error (when I try to run it under `strace` I get a different error, which is really strange). I don't know of solution other than using a Cygwin shell.

Comment: "`*/*`" worked for me on Win8 from ConEmu, cmd and bash. However, runs this command from bash is slighty different - it use arguments piping instead of appnding them to command line of grep.exe. Also, you may run bash as shell for ConEmu

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`*/*` is not correct for the current directory in unix style terminal emulators,</strike> use `./*` or even just `.` would work.

Using `.` or `./*` may be unnecessary but might get around the invalid argument problem.

Comment: In Unix and Unix-like shells, `*/*` is a valid wildcard; it expands to a list of everything in subdirectories of the current directory. `./*` refers to everything in the current directory, and `.` is just the current directory itself; neither is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: You thought *what* was `./**/*`? In a Unix shell, `**` is generally the same as `*`. The leading `./` is not necessary.

Comment: It seems ** for all sub directories (recursive) is a bash only thing

Comment: I've just tried grep -r 'some string' \*/* in both Cygwin and in Console2. In Cygwin, ./\* returned the same as \*/*. In Console2, it returned matches for one random subdirectory, then it quit without searching any other directories or the current direcotory. I then tried it with a different string, one that I know exists in some files in some subdirectories, and it executed without finding these matches.

Comment: @QuestionMark: bash treats `**` as equivalent to `*` by default. It treats `**` specially only if the `globstar` option is set (`shopt -s globstar`. zsh recognizes `**` by default.